# Crystal Reports massive generator

Tags: c#, security, crystal-reports

I have problems connecting to the report's database. In my log I see that an exception is thrown : "Log on failed".

This is what I do: I am using a service that needs to massive generate reports. When opening the report with Crystal Reports everything is ok, but when using this service, it throws an exception saying log on failed.

I tried Verify Database from the menu in Crystal Reports but it says everything is up to date. My service uses a batch for massive generating reports on the server. I am unable to connect to the database.

I think that there are some security issues when trying to connect to the database like this. I can't do any debug, except logging my steps.

Please help !

Comment: What type of database are you accessing - Oracle, SQLServer, etc? How are you running Crystal Reports in batch?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a "canned" Crystal Reports batch scheduler like:

http://www.reportrunner.com

http://www.christainsteven.com